# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist while creating the table

Tags: oracle, create-table, ora-00942

I am creating a table in an oracle database using a statement like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE T_MY_NEW_TABLE (
      ID        VARCHAR2(10 char) not null,
      VERSION   NUMBER(4),
      SOME_ID   VARCHAR2(10 char) not null,
      constraint PK_MY_NEW_TABLE primary key(ID)
 );
```

This script usually runs fine. But sometimes I get the error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
Which doesn't make any sense to me. What is the error supposed to mean?
I am creating a new table. The table that I am creating should not exist. But oracle want it to exist, so I can create it?

It must be something else. And only the error is misleading?

I tried to create a new table.
I expected the new table to be created.
Sometimes I am getting the error ORA-00942 instead of the created table.

Comment: For that statement, or for a different one - perhaps one with a foreign key constraint that does reference a table that doesn't yet exist? (But might by the time you try again, if you have a script creating them out of order...)

Comment: Another one possible option: database trigger that does something with not existing object. There should be more information on the object name in a stack

Comment: Possibly a DDL trigger trying to do something when a CREATE occurs. Check DBA_TRIGGERS for that, or throw on a SQL trace which will capture more details